# how can I keep a list of FireDAC bookmarks with a name?

Tags: delphi

I am using last delphi version and I would like to have something like a TStringList (where I can keep a list of strings with an integer TObject linked) but instead of an integer TObject I need a list of bookmark.

I tried with generics

```
mySL: TList<TBookmark>;
```

but I have managed just to save the bookmarks without the description.
I would like to be able to do something like:

```
var myBookmark1 := TBookmark(mySL('test1'));
var myBookmark2 := TBookmark(mySL('test2'));
```

Could you help me?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics is the easiest solution, indeed, but you should use a TDictionary (a collection of key-value pairs) instead of a TList (a collection of just values). This way you can associate a key to each bookmark.

```
var 
  mySL: TDictionary<String, TBookmark>;
  Bookmark: TBookmark;
begin
  ...
  ...
  // Create the Dictionary
  mySL := TDictionary<String, TBookmark>.Create;
  // Store Bookmarks
  mySL.Add('Starting Position', MyQuery.GetBookmark);
  ...
  // Retrieve Bookmarks
  mySL.TryGetValue('Starting Position', Bookmark);
  ...
end
```

The method TryGetValue will return you a boolean, informing you if the bookmarks has been found (and set to the Bookmark variable) or it doesn't exist.